# Parse RSS pubDate to Date object in java

Tags: java, date, rss, date-format

How can I parse a pubDate from a RSS feed to a Date object in java.

The format in the RSS feed:
Sat, 24 Apr 2010 14:01:00 GMT

What I have at the moment:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getInstance();
Date pubDate = dateFormat.parse(item.getPubDate().getText());
```

But this code throws an ParseException with the message Unparseable date

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can define the date format you are trying to parse, using the class [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
Date date = formatter.parse("Sat, 24 Apr 2010 14:01:00 GMT");
```

Additionally, for non-English [`Locale`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html)'s, be sure to use the following when parsing dates in English:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 14):

If you need to have an RFC822 compliant date, try this :

```
DateFormat dateFormatterRssPubDate = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 7):

For the lucky one that can use the Java 8 LocalDateTime:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.from(DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME.parse("Sat, 24 Apr 2010 14:01:00 GMT"));
```

Comment: That’s not only easier, it’s first and foremost less errorprone. Thanks. PS `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter` have been backported to Java 6 and 7 in [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).

Comment: Exception when: 'Tue, 12 Mar 2019 10:05:52 EDT' and
Text 'Wed, 6 Mar 2019 14:05:00 PST' could not be parsed at index 25.

Comment: @DanielDeLeón That seems to agree with [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME): *North American zone names and military zone names are not handled.* I gather that RSS follows RFC 822 here, and that PST, PDT, MST, MDT, CST, CDT, EST and EDT are allowed: [link](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc822/#z28).