# Parse DIFFERENT RSS pubDate to Date object in java

Tags: java, rss

i understood how to format the date according to this link
[parse exemple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705548/parse-rss-pubdate-to-date-object-in-java)

but my problem is a bit complex i have different  pubDate rss elements for example

Sun, 21 Aug 2011 20:19:47 +0200
or

Sun, 21 Aug 2011 10:01

what is the best why to set one format for any pubDate element

Comment: I wouldn't trust anything someone called "enter link description here" told me, anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSS pubDate must conform to the [RFC 822 Date/Time specification](http://asg.web.cmu.edu/rfc/rfc822.html#sec-5). You can use the same `DateFormat` object from your [parsing link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705548/parse-rss-pubdate-to-date-object-in-java) to get the proper string from a java `Date`.

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
String pubDateText = formatter.format(pubDate);
```

Where pubDate is a previously defined Date object. This will always return the same format.