# String dateTime to Date -> check if is today

Tags: android, date, format

I need a function that checks if a date from a rss feed (of an event) is today. The rss gives a String (between CDATA) so i need to parse that. The form of this Date is:

> Wed, 01 Aug 2012 00:00:00 +0002

where the time and timezone are useless, only date counts.

I thought: i format the date of today (set phone date wrong for testing) in the same format as the input string and test of they are equal. But apparently the language settings of the device are important to, because i got:

```
 Wed, 01 Aug 2012 00:00:00 +0002 = wo, 01 aug. 2012 14:36:55 +0200
```

(i would use a substring to get rid of the time).
So this doesn't work.

Now i tried a new way, but it seems a bit overcomplicated:
Get string --> convert to date --> format date to string in ddMMyyyy form -->
format today date to string in ddMMyyyy form -->
test if they are equal.
But for some reason this doesnt work either, because the parsing from string to Date doesnt work. But i thought my format was exactly the same...
Anyone has an idea how to achieve this, or what i should change?

my code:

```
public boolean isAgendaToday(String inputstring){
          boolean isToday = false;
          SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");  
            Date deventDate = null;
            String seventDate;
             Date dtoday = new Date();
             String stoday;
             SimpleDateFormat dateOnly = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
             stoday = dateOnly.format(dtoday);
             try {  
                deventDate = format.parse(inputstring); 
                seventDate = dateOnly.format(deventDate);
                 System.out.println(seventDate + " = " + stoday);
                if(stoday.equals(seventDate)){
                     isToday = true;
                 }
            } catch (ParseException e) {  
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                // XXX Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return isToday;

      }
```

This is what the log says after every time i try this (with different dates of course):

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: Tue, 31 Jul 2012 00:00:00 +0002

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705548/parse-rss-pubdate-to-date-object-in-java, with the date available, you can just check if it's the current day

Comment: I would dispute that the time zone is irrelevant - my idea of "today" may not be the same as yours.

Comment: @JonSkeet  i only want to compare dates, and because of the date of my phone depends on the timezone; the timezone i get from the RSS is irrelevant.

Comment: @Jasper: It depends on what you're trying to achieve - but if you're trying to determine whether something was posted in your local "today" then you *do* need to take the RSS time zone into account, because you want to first resolve that to an absolute time. You can then work out that absolute time in your *phone's* time zone, and see whether that's today.

Comment: @JonSkeet: You are right, thank you for thinking along. But in the context of this application it won't really matter, but for the exactness of the pure usage of the method it should be taken into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        Date date = null;
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z",Locale.ENGLISH);
        try
        {
            date = format.parse("Wed, 01 Aug 2012 00:00:00 +0002");
        }
        catch (ParseException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Date current = new Date();
        if (date != null)
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + current.compareTo(date), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I think this code make things that you want - date from RSS is created depends on provided fields and new Date() create date depends on your current datetime and timestamps have to be the same.

But if you want check only date without time you can set hours, minutes and seconds to '0'

Comment: thanks, it was indeed the locale.ENGLISH that did the trick. Only needed to add that to my code and it worked.

Comment: You don't need to create strings from date and then compare strings. You can compare dates =)

Comment: but then the time has to match as well, doesnt it?