# Parsing long date in Android with SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, android, datetime, simpledateformat

How should I configure SimpleDateFormat in order to be able to parse the following date: 
*Thu, 4 Apr 2013 00:00:00 CET*

I tried:
`new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");`
But it got the following exception:

```
ERROR java.text.ParseException:
Unparseable date: "Thu, 4 Apr 2013 00:00:00 CET"
```

Comment: "it did not worked" is not a useful description of your symptoms.

Comment: Wouldn't `dd` apply for `04` only? Just an idea...

Comment: Also, seems like your format is missing the comma after the day name...

Comment: Here is the same problem with a solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705548/parse-rss-pubdate-to-date-object-in-java

Comment: Also note that `SimpleDateFormat` is [locale sensitive](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5174696/27190)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be missing a comma.  Try:

```
SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
Date d = sf.parse("Thu, 4 Apr 2013 00:00:00 CET")
```